# icedtea-plugin not working in chromium

Tags: java, chromium, icedtea

The icedtea plugin is working in firefox, but not in Chromium. Chromium shows in about:plugins

```
IcedTea-Web Plugin (using IcedTea-Web 1.2 (1.2-2ubuntu1.1))
The IcedTea-Web Plugin executes Java applets.
```

but java web apps are not starting. I have

```
apt-cache policy icedtea-plugin
icedtea-plugin:
  Installed: 1.2-2ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 1.2-2ubuntu1.1

apt-cache policy openjdk-6-jre
openjdk-6-jre:
  Installed: 6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Candidate: 6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.12.04.1

apt-cache policy chromium-browser
chromium-browser:
  Installed: 18.0.1025.168~r134367-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Candidate: 18.0.1025.168~r134367-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

apt-cache policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 14.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Candidate: 14.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
```

installed and am very greatful for all suggestions and ideas.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [bug 1025553](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1025553). Feel free to subscribe to the bug to be notified when it's fixed.